# "Leave Open" is missing!

Tags: feature-request, review

When you review a [close vote](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close), you'll get:

[image]

You click on **Close** and to get to the options:

- duplicate
- ...

When you click on the close under the body of the [question itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/328807/19341), you can't vote for **Leave Open**!

Can we have it there?

Comment: You can't vote for "Leave Open", but if the question does get closed, you can vote for "reopen". It is not clear to me that the suggested option is better than what we have. I'm happy to see what others think (or whether this has been extensively discussed already elsewhere).

Comment: Wouldn't this take a lot of monitoring till I could vote for reopen?

Comment: It might mean occasionally having a look to see whether the question has been closed. If you feel strongly about some question, I don't think that's too much to ask. I forgot to mention, there is also a thread here on meta where one can post requests to reopen: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes

Comment: I'm assuming that the leave-open bit will have improved functionality at some indetermined time in the future, or is there solely so that users don't feel obligated to vote to close. Perhaps it also has something to do with how long it stays in the review-queue (unlike some of the others, it does not make sense if only one user reviews it). While it is possible for mods to look over the stats of leave open vs. closed, it's poorly formatted and not easy. That aside, it is sometimes taken as convention that a user 'votes to remain open' in the comments (and one user won't try to close).

Answer (score 3):

The "leave open" button doesn't do all that much, and it would not make a lot of sense to have it outside of the review queue. The major effect of it is that if enough users select "leave open", [the question will be removed from the review queue and close votes start aging immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/151385).

The removal from the review queue is irrelevant outside of review itself, and the close vote aging also doesn't matter once the question has 100 views or is dealt with in the review queue.